# In Python read a file content from input and write into output but same content shouldn't append to output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a requirement in python to read a file from input where data is fed and write that data to the output file, but before it writes/appends the data into the output file I have to check (compare with existing data in output file):

- if the same data is fed once again, it shouldn't write/append to output file (no duplicates)
- if the data is different, then only append to output file

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have written a process file in python and able to read input files content and writing to output file but when i run process file again same data is appending to output file without proper check. same content shouldn't be append

Comment: Give a [mcve] showing how you've tried to solve the problem and where it's coming up short.

Answer (score -1):

At last I resolved it myself. Here is the code:

```
Input file: ifile.txt
>>> This is my input file data

output file: ofile.txt
>>> hello

process file: process.py

""" Not to append duplicate data to output file"""

existingLines = set(line.strip() for line in open('ofile.txt'))

outfile = open("ofile.txt", "a+")
for content in open('ifile.txt', "r"):
    if content not in existingLines: # to void duplicate lines
        outfile.write(content+'\n')
        existingLines.add(content)
outfile.close()
```

so now if I run process file again with using the same data of inputfile this data wont be appended to outputfile.

Output will be:

```
hello
This is my input file data
```